# Plotting issue when using HeavisideTheta or Piecewise

Tags: plotting

I am currently using *Mathematica 13.0* on Mac OS.

I have noticed a strange behavior when increasing the plot interval of a function. This appears both with `HeavisideTheta` and with `Piecewise`.

More specifically, when I plot

```
Plot[(Exp[x] - 1.94) HeavisideTheta[Exp[x] - 1.94] - (Exp[x]-2.728) HeavisideTheta[Exp[x] - 2.778], {x, 0, 1}]
```

and with Piecewise:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[x] - 1.94, Exp[x] > 1.94}, {0,Exp[x] <= 1.94}}] - Piecewise[{{Exp[x] - 2.728, Exp[x] > 2.728}, {0,Exp[x] <= 2.728}}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I obtain a nice looking graph, and this follows on the intervals $(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), \cdots, (0,5)$. However, afterwards some weird things start to happen, specifically when I plot on the interval $(0,10)$:

[image]

The $y$ range in the above case goes from $(0,0.8)$ to $(0.788,0.788+\epsilon)?$ These "oscillations" disappear when I add the option `PlotRange->All` (as would be expected), namely

```
Plot[(Exp[x] - 1.94) HeavisideTheta[Exp[x] - 1.94] - (Exp[x] - 2.728) HeavisideTheta[Exp[x] - 2.778], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But why dos `Plot` restrict the plotting range as shown in the picture?

Comment: Look at the scale on the left side. The plot shows a nearly constant number and the very small variations are caused by floating points errors. Use the option PlotRange->{0,1} to get a more helpful plot.

Comment: As @DanielHuber pointed out the problem are small floating point errors at large x when computing differences between extremely large numbers. Choosing a better `PlotRange` like `{0,1}` (as proposed by @DanielHuber) or in this case also `All` helps. Alternatively one can increase the `WorkingPrecision` of `Plot`.